# Ruby on Rails to Ionic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ionic-framework

I have a working Ruby on Rails application that I would like to bundle with Ionic.

How do I show my RoR pages in the Ionic app? Do I have to treat it as an API? What happens to the RoR styling?

I have read http://www.dovetaildigital.io/blog/2015/8/21/rails-and-ionic-make-love-part-one but am unsure how to make this work for my application.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to access dynamic information from Rails application is to use API. The trick is to use RESTful routes to handle HTTP calls when you develop your RoR application. Check out [this article](http://blog.jamesalmond.com/resourceful-routing-with-rails/). Of course you can point ionic (basically phonegap) to load externally hosted mobile friendly RoR application if that fulfills your need reasonably.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for rendering data from the Rails backend in an Ionic app is to access the data as JSON.

See the documentation on the Angular HTTP module here.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Another option would be to return HTML, but you'll lose a lot of benefits on Angular presenting it this way.

Thanks,
Dan